# Use Infiltrator.jl on package code without adding Infitrator to Project.toml

Tags: julia

Is it possible to use `@infiltrate` from [Infiltrator.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDebug/Infiltrator.jl) to inspect a function in a package without adding Infiltrator to the Project.toml file? I have Infiltrator installed in my 1.7 environment, so I was hoping that stacked environments would come into play, but apparently not:

```
julia> using PackageFoo
[ Info: Precompiling PackageFoo [b7d5e62f-924e-4906-b2b5-430ba4531d91]
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: @infiltrate not defined
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, hence the comment, but the discussion in this thread may be useful:

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/separate-dev-packages-in-project-toml/63143

Answer (score 2):

The current working solution is to do

```
Main.@infiltrate
```

from within your package.

I keep

```
using Infiltrator
```

in my `startup.jl` so that it's always pulled from the 1.7 environment regardless of which package or other environment I'm using.

Note that you need to first load your package without that line, then rely on `Revise` to notice when you add the `Main.@infiltrate` line to your package.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use a [system image](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/sysimg/#System-Image-Building). In the following code I use PackageCompiler.jl to [create a system image](https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/sysimages.html) that includes Infiltrator.jl, that way `Main`, the top-level module, will always include `Infiltrator` as a submodule:

```
julia> using PackageCompiler

julia> create_sysimage(["Infiltrator"]; sysimage_path="debug_image.so")
```

I save the new system image to `debug_image.so` and then start julia with this image instead of the default one, the `NoInfil` project does not have `Infiltrator` in its deps:

```
$ julia --project=NoInfil -Jdebug_image.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [21:52:23]
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.7.1 (2021-12-22)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> using NoInfil

julia> NoInfil.greet()
Infiltrating greet() at NoInfil.jl:3:

infil>
```

This is what `NoInfil/src/NoInfil.jl` looks like:

```
module NoInfil

greet() = (Main.Infiltrator.@infiltrate; print("Hello World!"))

end # module
```

Comment: This is a useful answer, but I don't think I will mark it as the accepted answer. I guess the straightforward answer is "No, there is no easy way to use Infiltrator on package code without adding Infiltrator to the Project.toml file."

Answer (score 0):

Probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/73252860/500314 is the way to go.

Another option is described in the [Infiltrator readme](https://github.com/JuliaDebug/Infiltrator.jl). Instead of calling `Main.@infiltrate` directly, one can use the more verbose:

```
if isdefined(Main, :Infiltrator)
    Main.infiltrate(@__MODULE__, Base.@locals, @__FILE__, @__LINE__)
end
```

This runtime check avoids errors during package precompilation.